# Is there a place that lists graduate institutions and their specialties?

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm currently a sophomore at a Canadian university, and due to some recent head butts in a few maths classes, I'm realizing I don't know what I want to do in grad school (or if I even want to go for mathematics alone).

I'm currently interested in differential geometry, combinatorial optimization and applied mathematics, despite doing poorly in a discrete course and modelling course (are these red flags that indicate I should consider other fields)? I'm also planning my upper level course (which I know will weigh more on grad school applications), but I don't even know what to take? **Is there a list somewhere with brief descriptions of different institutions (I'm interested in Canadian, US, and UK institutions)?** I'm hoping maybe finding a good program for myself would give me some guidance on courses to take too.

Also, are there institutions that combine maths with non-science disciplines? Is that even a thing that is possible in grad school (masters or PhD, however, I was told the two were quite different to answer, so I understand if it's too broad a question). Another worry is that I'll go to grad school and end up getting bored of what I do, so how does one combat that before they go in, or even apply?

Thanks in advance for any answers, I'm just having a typical second-year crisis where I don't know what to do, and thought it was time I got myself some answers.

Comment: Unlike some places in Europe, most US institutions have many specialties in their math departments.  Your best bet is to go to the individual department websites and look around.

Comment: What's the content of the discrete course? Whether this is a red flag depends on the reasons you're not doing well. As for non-science disciplines that can be combined with math, the only things that come to mind are: math education, history of math/science, philosophy of math (especially logic). Also, you say you're a "sophomore" - are you in a three-year bachelor's or a four-year?

Comment: I am in a four year bachelor's right now. The discrete course I took was offered by the software eng dept. but covered pure maths topics including some logic, algorithms, intro to proofs, graph theory and combinatorics, and also brief probability theory via counting. I was doing well in the course until the exam because I went from a B+ to a C.
And thanks for the non-maths discipline relations, it was good to note.

Comment: Also, thanks for the comment @vadim123, that's what I've been doing so good to know I'm on the right track.

Comment: To know if it's a red flag for math, you need to know if the it's the mathematical content that made it difficult for you. For example, if you just didn't study for it, that's a different reason. As a general rule, getting a C in a math class when there's no particular reason is an indication of something. If you've had tons of other classes where you've done well, that's another matter.

Comment: I'm sure it was the case of your example. I still enjoy a lot of the content that was taught, but I didn't prepare enough for certain aspects of my final that were asked about more than I expected. In any case, the lowest mark I've received in my other maths (calc and alg) classes has been a B+ so far, so I don't know if I'm just bad at this sort of "pure" stuff. I'll be taking combinatorics next year, so I guess we'll see then.

Answer (score 1):

The American Mathematical Society maintains a [searchable database](http://www.ams.org/programs/students/findgradprograms/fgp-search) with specialties of US and Canadian institutions.